# How Can I Generate Randomized Text-Based Bingo Cards with Unique Columns

Tags: excel, random, excel-formula

For a variety of reasons, I'm trying to develop

- A bingo card
- of text options
- from a table of 5 columns and *n* rows (named Options)
- with each column only pulling from a single column
- with unique answers from each
- without adding a column of numbers using rand()
- using Excel 365
- that doesn't require a rand() column

Example: Party Bingo, where columns are categories of things having to do with Music, Food & Drink, Games, People, Misc.
[Example Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7FrK.png) | [Example Resulting Card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5lNY.png)

I want **B** to only pull from **Music**, and **I** to only pull from **Food & Drink**, etc.

I would like this to be dynamic, because the columns don't all have the same number of entries.
So, I was trying to account for empty cells, which gave me this - unfortunately it doesn't spill so I don't get unique answers

> `=LET(filt,FILTER(Options,Options[Music]<>""),(INDEX(filt,RANDBETWEEN(1,ROWS(filt)),1)))`

I'm starting to think there's no way I can do 1 function and get a 5x5 array like this, so now I'm trying to figure how to do a different function for each of the **B I N G O** columns that spills down so I can get unique options for each.

I tried this but I definitely messed something up here because it returns '#REF!' most of the time

> `=LET(filt,FILTER(Options,Options[Food & Drink]<>""),INDEX(filt,SEQUENCE(5),2,RANDARRAY(5,1,1,COUNTA(filt))))`

I feel like I'm on the right track but I'm hitting a wall.
Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this formula:

```
=LET(d,Options,cntRows,5,
cntCol,COLUMNS(d),
λCleanData,LAMBDA(d,cntMin,TAKE(d,MAX(cntMin,COUNTA(d)))),
λRandomSort,LAMBDA(x,cntR,SUBSTITUTE(TAKE(SORTBY(x,RANDARRAY(ROWS(x))),cntR),0,"-")),
DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(1,cntCol),LAMBDA(r,c,
                         HSTACK(r,λRandomSort(λCleanData(INDEX(Options,,c),cntRows),cntRows)))),0,1))
```

[image]

`λCleanData` returns the values of one column - based on the minimum number of rows - if there are empty rows. This is necessary as otherwise too many empty cells might be returned by the random sorting.

`λRandomSort` does the random sorting on a column.

`REDUCE` together with `HSTACK` can handle unequal column sizes. I tried `BYCOL` together with the λ-function but that returns errors.

**UPDATE to not replace 0 within card**

```
=LET(d,Options,cntRows,5,
cntCol,COLUMNS(d),
λCleanData,LAMBDA(d,cntMin,MAP(TAKE(d,MAX(cntMin,COUNTA(d))),LAMBDA(a,IF(a=0,"-",a)))),
λSort,LAMBDA(x,cntR,TAKE(SORTBY(x,RANDARRAY(ROWS(x))),cntR)),
DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(1,cntCol),LAMBDA(r,c,
                         HSTACK(r,λSort(λCleanData(INDEX(Options,,c),cntRows),cntRows)))),0,1))
```

λCleanData now returns a - instead of 0 in case of an empty cell.

Comment: Oh man thank you, this is exactly it! And thank you for the explanation too, I'm going to use this as a jumping off point to learn all the functions I don't already know in it. Thanks!

Comment: Actually - just realized, for some reason for anything this returns, all 0's are replaced with hyphens (-), including within the text of the cell (for example, "$10" returns "$1-"). I'm thinking this is from `λRandomSort,LAMBDA(x,cntR,SUBSTITUTE(TAKE(SORTBY(x,RANDARRAY(ROWS(x))),cntR),0,"-"))` - I replaced the `0` at the end with `""` and I think it's working, but any reason that could cause a problem?

Comment: I added a solution where 0 doesn't get replaced.